# Cambiar Formato de fecha sustraída de la curp

Tags: php

¿Cómo se podría cambiar el formato una fecha la cual sustraigo de la curp
630612 y pasarlo al formato 1963-06-12

```
$curp = "xxxx630612xxxxxxxx";

$rest = substr($curp, 4, -8);  // devuelve "630612"


 $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymd', $rest);
 echo $newDate = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

pero me devuelve 2063-06-12 y no 1963-06-12

Answer (score 0):

Añádele tú mismo el "siglo". PHP no tiene cómo saber qué '63' es '1963' y te devuelve su mejor suposición. Luego le dices que el formato es un año de 4 dígitos:

```
$curp = "xxxx630612xxxxxxxx";

$rest = substr($curp, 4, -8);  // devuelve "630612"
$rest1900 = '19'.$rest; // "19630612"

$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $rest1900);
echo $newDate = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

> **Nota:**
>   Para los formatos y e yy, los años por debajo de 100 son tratados de manera especial cuando se emplean los símbolos y o yy. Si el año cae en el rango de 0 (inclusive) a 69 (inclusive), se añade 2000. Si el año cae en el rango de 70 (inclusive) a 99 (inclusive) se añade 1900. Esto significa que "00-01-01" se interpreta como "2000-01-01".

Comment: Te añadí la nota del manual que explica el comportamiento que el OP menciona. Saludos.

Comment: Probablemente esto se deba a que los UNIX TIMESTAMP existen entre 1970 y 2069. Buena adición.